# What is the difference between `linetype <colorspec>` and `linecolor <colorspec>` during setting a `linestyle` in Gnuplot

Tags: colors, gnuplot

I know, that during the definition of a `line style`

```
set colors classic
set style line 1 lt 2
```

will "import" the color (green) and the point type (rotated crosses) of `linetype` 2. If I want to change only the color of the `line style`, I have to use a `colorspec`. However, I cannot see the difference between

```
set style line 1 lt rgb "green"
```

and

```
set style line 1 lc rgb "green"
```

What is the difference? If it matters, I am using `Gnuplot` version 5+.

Answer (score 0):

If you check `help linetype`:

> The set linetype command allows you to redefine the basic
> linetypes used for plots. The command options are identical to those
> for "set style line". Unlike line styles, redefinitions by set
> linetype are persistent; they are not affected by reset.

**Script:**

```
### linetype and linestyle
reset session

set linetype 1 lc rgb "red" lw 3 dt 3

set style line 1 lt      rgb "green"   # Setting 1
set style line 2 lc      rgb "green"   # Setting 2
set style line 3 lt 1 lc rgb "green"   # Setting 3

set key out
plot 1*x ls 1, 2*x ls 2, 3*x ls 3

pause -1

reset
set key out
plot 1*x ls 1, 2*x ls 2, 3*x ls 3

pause -1

reset session
set key out
plot 1*x ls 1, 2*x ls 2, 3*x ls 3
### end of script
```

My limited understanding is the following:
I assume that there is probably no difference between

`set style line 1 lt      rgb "green"` and

`set style line 2 lc      rgb "green"`

Actually, I am wondering why in the first setting `lt` is not seen as an error.

In Setting 3: `set style line 3 lt 1 lc rgb "green"`

you take the line properties from `linetype 1` but overwrite the linecolor with `"green"`.

So, for the first plot all lines will be green, but the 3rd line has `lw 3` and `dt 3`.

[image]

For the second plot (after `reset`) the linestyles will be erased (i.e. set to default), but the first curve will get the properties of `lt 1` (i.e. `"red"`, `lw 3` and `dt 3`)

[image]

For the third plot (after `reset session`) all linestyles are set to default, for the first curve `lw 3` and `dt 3` are kept, but apparently the color of linetype 1 is reset to default and not kept.

[image]

Hmm, confusing... Once Ethan mentioned (I forgot where) that there are "historical reasons" behind `linetype` vs. `linestyle`.

Check `help linestyles vs linetypes`, this should be an attempt to explain.

> **linestyles vs linetypes**
>
> A linestyle is a temporary association of
> properties linecolor, linewidth, dashtype, and pointtype. It is
> defined using the command set style line. Once you have defined a
> linestyle, you can use it in a plot command to control the appearance
> of one or more plot elements. In other words, it is just like a
> linetype except for its lifetime. Whereas linetypes are permanent
> (they last until you explicitly redefine them), linestyles last until
> the next reset of the graphics state.